# sendmail access table

Tags: linux, email, email-server, sendmail

I've block a domain abc.com in sendmail access table. i.e:

```
abc.com    REJECT
```

Now i want to allow above domain for xyz.com. I've tried this as below,

```
xyz.com    RELAY
abc.com    REJECT
```

But it did not work. Is there any other way to allow a rejected domain for a single domain. In other words block abc.com for all but allow for xyz.com

It works with xyz.com RELAY.

As per below rule in sendmail access file, when a user from: any@xyz.com to any@abc.com send email, It is being blocking by sendmail.

```
xyz.com    RELAY
abc.com    REJECT
```

But I want to allow xyz.com to send email to abc.com whatever it is blocked in access file for other domains/users. So that is why I first RELAY xyz.com and then reject abc.com. Its not working. is there any possibility to do as i want.

Is there not any way to do this?

Comment: Any help in this regard?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is documented here: http://www.sendmail.org/tips/relaying

Essentially:

Add "xyz.com RELAY" to /etc/mail/access

```
echo "xyz.com RELAY" >> /etc/mail/access
```

Then run;

```
makemap hash /etc/mail/access.db < /etc/mail/access
```

Comment: +1 for the makemap. It is not enough to edit the file. You have to run makemap next for the changes to take effect